# unable to retrieve the value of the series object in the highchart tooltip

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to implement the tooltip for whisker bloxplotchart highchart and unable to retrieve the value of the series in my tooltip.  The interpolation in the tooltip looks fine to me. 
Not sure what i am doing wrong ? Please find my code below.

bloxplot component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-box-plot-chart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})
export class BoxPlotChartComponent {

    public options: any;
    chart: any;

    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public moduleName: string;

    constructor() {

        this.options = {

            chart: {
                type: 'boxplot'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }, plotLines: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:{point.color}">{point.key}</strong><br><br><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td>low : </td>' +
                                 '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{series.low} </b></td></tr>' +
                              '<tr><td>q1 : </td>' +
                                 '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{series.q1} </b></td></tr>' +
                               '<tr><td>median: </td>' +
                                 '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{series.median} </b></td></tr>' ,
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this.chart.addSeries(this.series);

        if(this.moduleName == 'npv')
            this.options.tooltip.valueDecimals = 0;
    }

}
```

This is the series that i am binding to

```
 export interface BoxPlotSeriesData  {

        low: number;
        q1: number;
        median: number;
        q3: number;
        high: number;
        color: string;
        name: string;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to retrieve the value" ? Can you reproduce issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: {series.median} = > {{series.median}}. Interpolation with two brackets

Comment: it worked for me when i did for example {point.low}

Comment: Series object doesn't have properties like 
`median`, `q1` and `low`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qj778e5o/ (see `tooltip.formatter`). These're point's properties.